# Scrolling Spark List without Scroller bar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How to scroll Spark list with a disabled scroller bar? 
I created two buttons to scroll up and down, but it is unclear what methods can be used to scroll the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to disable the scroll bar.  You should create a custom skin for the scroll bar that uses your custom buttons and places them appropriately based on the design you want.

More info on [skinning a Scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSb04c7610c3432839-13869d09121418556f1-7ffc.html)

All that said, you can scroll a list by setting the [horizontalScrollPosition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#horizontalScrollPosition) or [verticalScrollPosition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#verticalScrollPosition) on it's [dataGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html#SkinPart%3adataGroup).  Conceptually something like this:

```
myList.dataGroup.horizontalScrollPosition = newPosition;
```